# OpenShift Update Channels Strategy

Tags: openshift

[image]

The above image is of the update graphs for **stable**, and **candidate** channels on OpenShift. I am a bit confused as to how it can be read or interpreted.

From the **stable** channel graph I interpret the following:

- Updates can be done from :

  - ***4.x.0*** to ***4.x.1***,
  - ***4.x.0*** to ***4.x.4***,
  - ***4.x.2***, and ***4.x.4***
- Updates can't be done from:

  - ***4.x.1***, ***4.x.2*** to ***4.x.4***

From the **candidate** channel graph I interpret the following:

- Updates can be done accordingly:

  - ***4.x.0*** to ***4.x.1***,
  - ***4.x.0*** to ***4.x.2***,
  - ***4.x.0*** to ***4.x.4***,
  - ***4.x.1*** to ***4.x.3***,
  - ***4.x.2*** to ***4.x.3***,
  - ***4.x.3*** to ***4.x.4***

But not sure if I have fully understood the interpretation.